# Identifying Power Connectors?

Tags: power, hardware

How do you go about identifying a female power connector if it doesn't say anywhere on the hardware or where I brought it from?

I have attached an image below, the male connector (battery) doesn't fit the female connector, would it simply be easier to just change them both to a more common connector?

[image]

Comment: the only things that really matter with headers are the size of the pins, the distance between them, the number of rows, and the number of columns

Comment: Well as you can see, there's just 2 pins. However it simply won't fit

Comment: well. is it only the plastic receptacle that is preventing this?

Comment: Yeah, i'd like it to have a proper fit. I have got the same female connector as seen on the battery im holding above. Should I just remove the one on the board and stick 2 wires in there and connect them wires to the female connector that will fit the male one above?

Comment: well, I don't have much advice there, and I say good luck, but you can always remove the plastic receptacle and turn it  into a bare header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the pitch (distance between the pins) first; that will help narrow down the choices. Go to Digikey and peruse the 2 pin cable mount (free hanging) connectors. Look through the photos until you see something that matches. It looks like a 0.100" pitch connector. There are a few main manufacturers of these type of connectors, with Molex and TE Connectivity being popular. Then there are a whole bunch of knockoffs of the popular connectors.